# unmount sshfs from mount point

Tags: sshfs, umount

mounted raspberry pi device via sshfs:

```
sshfs osmc@rpi.: /home/user/pi
```

mounting information:

```
user@azimuth:~$ mount | grep osmc

osmc@rpi.: on /home/user/pi type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Why am I unable to umount?

```
user@azimuth:~$ sudo umount /home/user/pi
[sudo] password for user: 
umount: /home/user/pi: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
```

How to unmount the sshfs share?

UPDATES:

```
user@azimuth:~$ sudo lsof | grep /home/user/pi
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.sshfs file system /home/user/nas
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo lsof | grep /home/user/pi`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since sshfs uses `fuse`, you need to use `fusermount -u` to unmount it:

```
fusermount -u /home/user/pi
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me, but required `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

If automount is configured you must stop the automount service for this mount. Use the start option to mount it again.

```
systemctl stop path-to-mountpoint.automount
```

You can check if automount is configured with

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type automount
```