# mount and umount commands hang

Tags: mount, vpn

I'm using a VPN to connect to my university network, then I mount a folder on my local machine using `sudo sshfs -o allow_other username@domain:/home/username /home/username`. This works well.

Later, I disconnect from the VPN, and later on I connect back and want to use the mounted folder, but it appears to "hang". This means that using `umount /home/username` hangs, as well as trying to run the mount command again.

Any ideas or command to "restart" the mount?

Comment: I don't think `umount` is the right thing to use on an SSHFS mount: see for example [unmount sshfs from mount point](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138944/178692)

Comment: getting `fusermount: failed to unmount /home/username: Device or resource busy`

Comment: You could try `fusermount -zu` - if that doesn't work, you may need to use `lsof` and/or `fuser` to identify and kill whatever process has file(s) open. See for example [sshfs device is busy](https://superuser.com/questions/207269/sshfs-device-is-busy)

Answer (score 0):

Based on an answer on Super User to this question: [sshfs device is busy](https://superuser.com/questions/207269/sshfs-device-is-busy), the only thing that worked for me is

```
sudo pkill -9 sshfs
```